# Need help structuring php

Tags: php

I need some help structuring my php. I am trying to get 3 different searches to work. one search is a regular text search which is default and is what is in the else statement. Here is a barebones of what I am doing to get the 2 searches to work. As you can see the script checked if media "all" was selected and if not, it uses the else statement to show the default search.

```
if(isset($_GET['media']) && 
    $_GET['media'] == 'all') 
    { //Code goes here for media search for all media results  }


else{ //code goes here for default search}
```

This works fine for the 2 searches but I have a third search I want to use but dont know how to implement it correctly.

the third search is for only media

```
if(isset($_GET['media']) && 
    $_GET['media'] == 'only') 
    { //Code goes here for media search for only media results  }
```

Basically all I am trying to figure out is how to get all 3 searches to work. I know why the first 2 will work because the IF and ELSE but I am not exactly sure how I would add in the ONLY media search. Can anyone give me some suggestions? thanks.

Comment: lots of great answers. Thanks everyone. It is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the cleanest method, and works faster by using a switch statement instead of a conditional `if/else` block.  Also, you can expand it further by just adding new cases (so you don't have to re-factor your `if/else` blocks in the future):

```
$media = isset($_GET['media']) ? $_GET['media'] : 'no_media';

switch($media) {
    case 'only':
        // search for only media
       break;
    case 'all':
        // search for text and media
       break;
    default:
        // search for just text, or the default.
       break;
}
```

Using a switch, PHP does not have to evaluate `$_GET['media']` over and over.

Comment: This does seem to be the best. The other way Reanimation posted works well too. Thanks.

Comment: Very clean, I just implemented it this way and it works great and made other things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:
You can use elseif as well.

```
if(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'all')
{ 
  // All media search
}
else if(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'only')
{
  // Only media search
}
else
{
  // Default search
}
```

[see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Okay I will gie that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you very much. I see what I did wrong when I was trying else if to begin with. I was using it after the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
if(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'all') 
{ //Code goes here for media search for all media results }
else if(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'only')
{ //Code goes here for media search for only media results }
else
{ //code goes here for default search }
```

Answer (score 1):

The elseif should work:

```
if(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'all') { 
//Code goes here for media search for all media results 
}
elseif(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'only') {
 //Code goes here for media search for only media results 
}
else{ 
//code goes here for default search
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you use the elseif(isset($_GET['media']) && $_GET['media'] == 'only')